# Is php://input secure? If not, how to secure it?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I recently watched video tutorial about Facebook Messenger Bot. To get messages from user who used my messenger bot, facebook send raw json to my server using php://input and then the my server send them back to facebook as a reply messages. Facebook didn't use any parameters for forwarding users messages to my server. I just afraid that someone attacking or gathering info about my server using my messenger bot.

Sample code that Mr.Tutorial used :

```
file_put_contents("fb.txt", file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

And here is the video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2KOqRceipM

Comment: Why do you save user input as a file on your server without any sanitization?

Comment: oh, to see json objects. That's not my code btw

Comment: If it was just a text file that would be downloaded when the user visited its url it would be relatively safer but what if somehow your server was made to execute any possible code in that file somehow? I would never save user input on server without any checks

Comment: the text file doesn't do anything, its just saving what facebook sent. And text file can't execute code right? I'm afraid when users send RCE using my bot, then the server get json from facebook and the server read a code in json objects that can remote my server. How to prevent this?

Comment: All you need to do is actually read the documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#security

Comment: thanks! i'll read it soon.

Answer (score 4):

`php://input` isn't any more or less secure than your telephone.  If you pick up the phone and someone tells you to burn your house down, do you burn your house down?  Probably not.

If you do something like `exec(php://input)` (psuedocode), you're going to have a bad day.  If instead you just read the input stream and properly handle the data you're getting, you're fine.

There's nothing inherently secure or insecure about the input stream.  It's what you do with it that matters.

Comment: what if the input is "exec(code())"? Is it still execute the code?

Comment: @KevinBradley What would `exec` the `exec`?  No, of course not, this wouldn't just happen on its own.  That would be a major security issue in PHP, making it completely useless for web applications.

Comment: no, is not `exec(exec(system('id')))` , that's ridiculous. So, is it safe to leave pure `php://input` ?

Comment: @KevinBradley There's nothing particularly unsafe about `php://input` on its own... it's what you do with it that matters.

Comment: ok, I understand. Should I add some filtering functions for `php://input`?

Comment: @KevinBradley For what?  As I said, what you do with it matters.  What would you filter for, and why?  You're asking the wrong questions...  Context is everything.  If you were asking about how to avoid SQL injection, for example, where the data came from is irrelevant to the solution.

Comment: im so sorry, my brain was freeze. Don't worry about SQL Injection, Im afraid of RCE..

Comment: @KevinBradley It's the same thing really... data used in the context of a command.  If the data isn't escaped/converted/transformed or otherwise kept in it's data context, you have a problem.  But again, none of that has to do with `php://input` itself.

Comment: Upload a PHP-embedded PNG image containing a exploit, and there provides the reason for filtering the input or data stream. This is a serious security flaw if binary data remains unfiltered from embedded script tags. Google it.